# How to "Forward to Other's Phone" using the RingCentral API?

Tags: ringcentral

Is there an API call that mimics the "Forward to Other's Phone" button under the "Call Handling and Forwarding" menu? I can add and edit a new "Call Forwarding Phone" via the REST API but can't find information on "Forward to Other's Phone".

This used to be called "Forward to other user's phones" in the previous UI.

The screenshot below shows where to find this feature in the Online Account Portal:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no API that handles the "Forward to Other's Phones" feature. As mentioned, "Add Call Forwarding Phone" feature is supported via the REST API.

Some differences between these two features include:

**Forward to Other's Phones**

- Only supports RingCentral digital line (aka DL) phone numbers which can be retrieved via the `/restapi/v1.0/account/{accountId}/devices` endpoint
- Call handling rules for the Other user are not executed, since the device is being connected directly
- Presence for the user the device belongs to does not get enabled because the current user is using the phone, not the owner of the phone.

**Call Forwarding Phone**

- Can be any PSTN phone number, except for RingCentral phone numbers in the same account
- Call handling rules on destination call forwarding number are executed (if on different RingCentral account)
- User presence on destination number is updated

When this API is available, I'll update this answer with an explanation of how to use this.